# Why when I insert a new linked list into unordered_map it does not save the entire list with links, but saves only first element of linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    string str;
    node* next;
};

int main(){
     unordered_map<int, node*> map;
     pair<int, node*> couple;
     int index;
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         string input;
         cout<<"Insert string: ";
         cin>>input;
         cout<<"Insert index: ";
         cin>>index;
         bool flag = false;
         for(const pair<int, node*>& n : map) {
              if(n.first == index){
                  flag = true;
              }
         }
         if(!flag){//if there is no such element, create
             node* temp = new node();
             temp->str = input;
             temp->next = NULL;
             couple = make_pair(index, temp);
             map.insert(couple);
         }
         else{//if there is, extend by creating a liked list
             node *head = map[index];
             while(map[index] != NULL){
                  map[index] = map[index]->next;
             }
             map[index] = new node();
             map[index]->str = input;
             map[index]->next = NULL;
             couple = make_pair(index, head);
             map.erase(index);
             map.insert(couple);
         }
     }  

     cout<<"\nEnter index to output: ";
     int i;
     cin>>i;
     node *temp = map[i];
     while(temp != NULL){
         cout<<temp->str<<" ";
         temp = temp->next;
     }  

     return 0;
}
```

**Short description:** 
The above program should store data in `unordered_map`. 
When there is no element `int` that a person is looking for in a `map`, create a new element using `index` and `node*`. I'm using `map.insert()` in this case. 
If the element that a person is looking for is present in a `map`, extend this element using `linked list` principle (to avoid collision).

**For example with wrong output:**

```
 Insert string: asd
 Insert index: 1
 Insert string: dsa
 Insert index: 1
 Insert string: dsada
 Insert index: 2  

 input index for output: 1
 asd//here is a problem
```

However the output should be:

```
input index for output: 1
asd
dsa
```

Comment: I have to ask, if you are already using `std::unordered_map`, why not also use `std::list` instead making your own list?

Comment: Every time you do `map[index] = ...` whether you modify that entry in the map or you add a new entry, depending on if `index` is already a key in the map or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver because I didnt know anything about std::list until you mentioned it

Comment: @rturrado I did not understand what you mean

Comment: @raksa `map.insert(couple);` -- This is a memory leak if `couple` already exists.  This is the danger of storing pointers to allocated memory as the data part of the map, and not checking if there already is an entry.

Comment: To add to a linked list, you have to set `next` to point to the next node. However the code never assigns anything but `NULL`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it always exists. I erase the whole element here`map.erase(index);` and then rewrite it  with a new list `map.insert(couple);`

Comment: @raksa That does not deallocate the memory.  All that does is remove the entry from the map, but the map has no idea *you* called `new` to allocate the memory.  As it stands now, you would be better off using `std::list` -- your code is full of memory leaks or potential memory leaks.

Comment: @BoP tried with setting next to a new node(), same effect

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry maybe I dont understand unordered_map, but in my mind it is almost same as 2d vector [ n x 2 ]. Basically you are saying that map cannot be replaced without deallocating memory?

Comment: @raksa -- Who called `new node()`?  For every call to `new`, you must supply the call to `delete`.  You did not do that.  The map has no idea how that pointer was created that you put into the map.  Also, why not create a real linked list *class*, and not try and manipulate `node` in the `main` program?  Otherwise `std::unordered_map<int, std::list<std::string>>` takes care of all of the issues you're seeing now.

Comment: @raksa [See this](https://ideone.com/MYFJ40).

Comment: `while(map[index] != NULL){ map[index] = map[index]->next;` causes you to lose the original `map[index]`, which is why all of the lists appear to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your main code can be initially simplified to the following:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1zax7MEYP)

```cpp
auto n{new node{input, nullptr}};  // create a new node

if (not map.contains(index)) {  // add a new list, containing the new node, to the map
    map[index] = n;
}
else {  // add the new node at the end of an existing list
    auto it{map[index]};
    for (; it->next != nullptr; it = it->next) {}
    it->next = n;
}
```

Explanation:

- Create a node `n`. You are always going to insert it, aren't you? If you didn't allow to have repeated strings in a list, then you should delay this creation.
- Since C++20, you can check the existence of a map key with [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains).
- If the key doesn't exist, create a new entry with `map[index] = n;`.
  Otherwise, get a `node*` to the head of the list with `map[index]`, walk the list using that pointer until you reach the last node, and make it point to the node you previously created.

So try not to fiddle too much with `map[index]`. Notice you only need to use it twice: 1) for adding a new entry, and 2) for getting the contents of an entry.

---

Now, the code aboves allocates memory that isn't deallocated at the end of the program. You could just use smart pointers to avoid that issue.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/xfcjTq4n4)

```cpp
struct node {
    std::string str;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};

std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<node>> map{};

auto n{std::make_unique<node>(input, nullptr)};  // create a new node

if (not map.contains(index)) {  // add a new list, containing the new node, to the map
    map[index] = std::move(n);
}
else {  // add the new node at the end of an existing list
    auto it{map[index].get()};
    for (; it->next != nullptr; it = it->next.get()) {}
    it->next = std::move(n);
}
```

---

And if you don't need to implement your own linked list, you could use `std::list`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/16eGfsrT7)

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, std::list<std::string>> map{};

if (not map.contains(index)) {  // add a new list, containing the new node, to the map
    map[index] = {input};
}
else {  // add the new node at the end of an existing list
    map[index].push_back(input);
}
```